# Android MapView Tiles Overlay: Image Stretching onZoom

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, tiles

I'm searching for a way to stretch/shrink images of the tile overlay (basically, a custom overlay that draws tile images on the map) when the map is being manipulated to zoom in/out.
If the zoom actually happens, the tiles are redrawn correctly in draw method of the Overlay class. But while user is still making the gesture (before he removes his fingers), the tiles are overlapped or drawn apart... I just can't find the way to catch these gesture changes and stretch the image. Or at least, not to draw the images so that there would be no bizarre visual effects.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understood: when I was drawing the image, I used the width and height of the image, but I had to recalculate the boundaries of the images every time using the projection's lonlatToPixels capability. Now that I've done this, the image is stretched/shrinked perfectly.